# How possible it is to have Peer to Peer connection transiting RFB protocol?

Tags: websocket, webrtc, p2p, rfb-protocol

I have been looking the possible solution, framework establishing p2p (Browser to Browser ) channel, to transit RFB protocol.

I am afraid i miss something over the net.

S.N: It should be possible with legacy architecture that with intermediate web server, that acts to transfer two unknown resources.

Answer (score -1):

I guess i should try with [this peer vnc](https://github.com/InstantWebP2P/peer-vnc) .